# how to change the class after button click

Tags: asp.net

This is webform1 code.I want to change the class of button after button click 
i call the javascript function on button click...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="valid_try2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript1.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <button id="btn" class="xx" name="btn" onclick="abc()">Button</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is stylesheet file where i create class

```
.xx {
    border: 5px solid green;    
}

.yy {
    border: 5px solid red;    
}
```

This is javascript file

```
function abc() {
    $("#btn").removeClass("xx");
    $("#btn").addClass("yy");
}
```

Comment: I see no jQuery reference in your html file. Are you getting a '$ is undefined' message in your browser, after checking inspect element?

Answer (score 2):

Your button will trigger a form post (PostBack), so all the things you do with `abc()` will be lost.

But since your tag is asp.net you can do this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="xx" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And then in code behind:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //change the class and do other stuff after the button click
        Button1.CssClass = "yy";
    }
```

If you mislabeled your question and you want a pure javascipt/css solution, add `type="button"` to the button and no form post will be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try below code snipped hope it will help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
   $("#p1").toggleClass('classB');
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.classA{color:red;}
.classB{color:yellow;}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<h2 class="">Click the button to change the class</h2>

<p id="p1" class="classA">I will be changed when you pressed click me</p>


<button>Click me </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
   $("#p1").toggleClass('classB');
    });
});

Comment: when i call above code in javascript file this is not run

Comment: I cant see you have imported the Jquery in your code

Comment: <script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: call this script before you import the your own javascript file and see whether it works or not.

Comment: in your js how you call abc() function?

Comment: sir the change not remain continues ..little time change occur after a second the first class apply..i change continues class

Comment: sir if i run the same code which you provide ..then it will change the class but for a sec not continuess

Comment: Impossible.check from your side any page refresh after the page loads

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks OK. Just add JQuery reference to aspx file.

Before  add the following line.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title></title>
    <style>
        .xx {
    border: 5px solid green;    
}

.yy {
    border: 5px solid red;    
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <button id="btn" class="xx" name="btn">Button</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#btn').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var a = $(this).attr('class');
                console.log(a);
                if (a === 'xx') {
                    $(this).removeAttr('class');
                    $(this).addClass("yy");
                } else {
                    $(this).removeAttr('class');
                    $(this).addClass("xx");
                }

            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```